# История болезни пациентов на php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть система для учета паспортных данных и истории болезней пациентов. Как добавлять паспортные данные в mysql все знают в принципе и историю болезней тоже можно так же добавить. Но возникает вопрос Паспортные данные записываются один раз а вот история болезней и повторный приём может повторятся несколько раз. Таким образом у каждого пациента на карте по несколько приёмов. И все эти данные о приёмах надо будет вывести на карте одного пациента.  Как быть в таком случае. Как можно реализовать эту схему на php mysql. Может есть у кого какие то идеи или где ни будь есть статьи.

Comment: Статьи есть [тут](https://google.gik-team.com/?q=sql+%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD+%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос простой, но я чувствую автору вопроса надо расписать принцип работы.

Допустим, у вас есть 2 таблицы, "карточки" и "приёмы".

"карточки"

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| номер карты | ФИО + паспорт |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 123         | lampa 123456  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

и "приёмы"

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| номер приёма | номер карты | описание |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 81           | 123         | ...      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Как можно увидеть, таблицы связываются между собой, а точнее таблица "приёмы" привязывается к таблице "карточки" с помощью колонки "номер карты", этот способ называется [Один ко многим](http://jtest.ru/bazyi-dannyix/sql-dlya-nachinayushhix-chast-3.html), как указал @Darth

И как пример кода:

```
$priem = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM приёмы WHERE `номер приёма`=$priem_id")->fetch();

$karto4ka = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM карточки WHERE `номер карты` = $priem->номер_карты")->fetch();
```

Comment: Спасибо, lampa, как раз то что нужно !